# Openquery to store procedure execution

Tags: sql-server

Is below executable in any sql server:

```
Create view example as(
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName, 'EXEC dbname.schema.spName @param1 = 123, @param2 = ''abc''')
)
```

If not:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CustomerOrdersView
AS
SELECT OrderId, OrderDate, TotalAmount
FROM OPENQUERY([YourLinkedServerName], 'EXEC dbo.GetCustomerOrders @CustomerId = 123')  -- Provide the desired customer ID
GO
```

Comment: Is your question "*is this code valid for any version of SQL Server?*"?

Comment: @J.D. Yes any sql server

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first one is valid syntax for any version of SQL Server (though typically you should avoid using `SELECT *` and list out the columns explicitly). The second one not so much, which is a little embarrassing because I'm pretty sure I'm the one who wrote that example.

The minor bug with this one:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CustomerOrdersView
AS
SELECT OrderId, OrderDate, TotalAmount
FROM OPENQUERY([YourLinkedServerName], 'EXEC dbo.GetCustomerOrders @CustomerId = 123')  -- Provide the desired customer ID
GO
```

Is that it's missing the database reference in the query that the `OPENQUERY()` call is making. Specifically `'EXEC dbo.GetCustomerOrders @CustomerId = 123'` should actually be `'EXEC DatabaseName.dbo.GetCustomerOrders @CustomerId = 123'` instead.

So the full correct code for that example would be:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CustomerOrdersView
AS
SELECT OrderId, OrderDate, TotalAmount
FROM OPENQUERY([YourLinkedServerName], 'EXEC DatabaseName.dbo.GetCustomerOrders @CustomerId = 123')  -- Provide the desired customer ID
GO
```

Comment: Thank u for your response. What’s wrong with the second one? Microsoft openquery says we can’t use it for calling extended sp. so how will this work? Many thanks

Comment: @SSR My answer mentions the mistake. It's just missing the database name in the query. It's valid once that's fixed (like the end of my answer does). You're not calling an extended stored procedure in the examples you provided (and extended stored procedures are deprecated and shouldn't be used in general).